# Xaml - combo box - why does selectedValue NOT work with multiple columns?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

Hi and thanks for your help.

The following xaml works just fine:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboCit_type"
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"    
  mvvm:View.FlowsWithPrevious="True"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cuCodeInfo.CitTypes}"
  SelectedValuePath="code" 
  DisplayMemberPath="code" 
  Text="{Binding cit_type}"
  IsEditable="true"
  IsReadOnly="false"
  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=cit_type}">
</ComboBox>
```

cuCodeInfo.CitTypes is simply a list of items that are available.  There are a number of public properties, but the 2 in question are "code" and "description".

Right now, I show the available code values and the user selects one.  If one was already selected, then it shows when the page is displayed.  This is all good.

So then I thought it might be nice to show both the code and the description.  I figured it shouldn't be too hard...

So I removed the DisplayMemberPath statement and added in an ItemTemplate.

When I did so everything looked great until I tried to select an item from the list.  When I did so, instead of showing the selected code, I would get an empty string.  I have searched the internet trying to find the one thing I need to add to the DataTemplate to fix this, but everything I have tried has failed.  Here is the code that is NOT working:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboCit_type"
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"    
  mvvm:View.FlowsWithPrevious="True"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cuCodeInfo.CitationTypes}"
  SelectedValuePath="code" 
  Text="{Binding cit_type}"
  IsEditable="true"
  IsReadOnly="false"
  SelectedValue="{Binding cit_type}">

  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=code}" mvvm:View.WidthEx="2" ></TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=description}" mvvm:View.WidthEx="15" Margin="1" ></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

As an aside, I have to use this exact same format (same list, etc. just different SelectedValue) in a number of forms - so if you want to suggest the best way to do this in xaml, that would be nice.  In my pre-xaml days, I would just create a control, set a property or 2, and use that in all my forms.  But I am supposed to use xaml, so am not sure of the best way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Use SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue

Comment: Works better, but now I see the name of the object that is List<>ed rather than the value.  It appears it is returning the object, not the value in SelectedValuePath.

Comment: You can extract that value from that object in code

Comment: But the user won't understand that the object name in the display portion represents data.  I just want the "code" value to show, not the name of the class.

Comment: IOW, I want it to work just like the first example, just show 2 columns instead of 1. I can't believe I have to use code-behind to get that UI.

Comment: I am saying in ViewModel where your binded property is. Can you please show your ViewModel code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe that I searched all over the net to find an answer and, until now, could not find one.  The answer is as easy as I thought it should be.

Just replace:
  DisplayMemberPath="code"
with 
  TextSearch.TextPath="code"
and the code works just fine.

Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an idea how to use SelectedItem

> ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            //Suppose your collection CitTypes is Initialized and filled with there Items
            //Now you can set first Element as selected in ComboBox 
            SelectedItem = CitTypes.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        CitType selectedItem;
        public CitType SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set { selectedItem = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }
        }
    }
```

> xaml

```
<ComboBox Name="cboCit_type"
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"    
mvvm:View.FlowsWithPrevious="True"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cuCodeInfo.CitationTypes}"
Text="{Binding cit_type}"
IsEditable="true"
IsReadOnly="false"
**SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"**>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing something like this.  Or just creating a property that combined the 2 values and using the first approach.  But I DON"T GET IT.  Why does MS make having 2 columns of data so MUCH MORE COMPLICATED than one column???? The first example (with one column) works just fine....

Comment: you try this you will get used to it.I think SelectedItem is more simple than SelectedValue. All what you need to take care is SelectedItem must be one of the element in list I mean there reference must be same.

Comment: Yeah, but I have a large number of properties that are determined by the comboBox UI. So now I have to create a 2nd property for each one that can hold the instance returned by SelectedItem and have the setter update the real property.  Yeah, it will work, but why doesn't MS just allow me to keep using DisplayMemberPath for multiple column comboBoxes????

Comment: Ok, found the answer.  Will post when they let me.  But just use TextSearch.TextPath and that will solve it.